# Change solution root folder icon in navigation options

Tags: outlook, navigation, outlook-addin, add-in

How do you change the icon of solution you that just got created? [Third item below is the solution that is an Add-in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60Lj.png) And the above three items above are its items.

Here is some part of the code

```
if (firstRun == true)
                {
                    solutionRoot =
                        rootStoreFolder.Folders.Add("Solution Demo",
                        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                    solutionCalendar = solutionRoot.Folders.Add(
                        solCal,
                        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                    solutionContacts = solutionRoot.Folders.Add(
                        "Solution Contacts",
                        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                    solutionTasks = solutionRoot.Folders.Add(
                        "Solution Tasks",
                        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks)
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                }
                else
                {
                    solutionRoot =
                        rootStoreFolder.Folders["Solution Demo"]
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                    solutionCalendar = solutionRoot.Folders[
                        "Solution Calendar"]
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                    solutionContacts = solutionRoot.Folders[
                        "Solution Contacts"]
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                    solutionTasks = solutionRoot.Folders[
                        "Solution Tasks"]
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [SetCustomIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/folder-setcustomicon-method-outlook) method of the `Folder` class.

The icon or bitmap resource can have a maximum size of 32x32. Icons that are 16x16 or 24x24 are also supported, and Microsoft Outlook can scale up a 16x16 icon if Outlook is running in high Dots Per Inch (DPI) mode. Icons of other sizes cause `SetCustomIcon` to return an error.

You can only call `SetCustomIcon` from code that runs in-process as Outlook. An `IPictureDisp` object cannot be marshaled across process boundaries. If you attempt to call `SetCustomIcon` from out-of-process code, an exception will occur.

The custom folder icon that this method provides does not persist beyond the running Outlook session. Add-ins therefore must set the custom folder icon every time that Outlook boots.
The custom folder icon does not appear in other Exchange clients such as Outlook Web Access, nor does it appear in Outlook running on a Windows Mobile device.

You can read more about Solutions module in the [Programming the Outlook 2010 Solutions Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692173(v=office.14).aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks for this. Maybe I have the wrong question. I want to change the icon in the Navigation options. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26dEJ.png) Third Icon. Thats on navigation options, buttom left of Outlook 2016.